# ExtJs : Migration to 6.5 from 6.2.1: $'{'framework.name'}'.properties does not exist

Tags: upgrade, extjs6, sencha-cmd

My current ExtJs application is built with version 6.2.1.

I installed the new Sencha Cmd 6.5
and also the ExtJS 6.5 framework, on this directory: "D:\TOOLS\Sencha\ext-6.5.0".

But when I launched the upgrade command :

```
sencha app upgrade -ext -path "D:\TOOLS\Sencha\ext-6.5.0"
```

First of all I've the following warning:

> [WRN] Disabling framework : current version 6.5.0.775 is incompatible with required version 6.2.1.167

And then the build failed on this error

> com.sencha.exceptions.ExNotFound: Required property file D:\AllAtrium\trunk\Web\src\trunk\FrontExtJs.sencha\app\$'{'framework.name'}'.properties does not exist

This missing variable is nevertheless declared into the file "MyApp\ext\cmd\sencha.cfg".

How to solve this issue ?

Is there a another way to migrate an app from v6.2 to v6.5 ?

*Full log :*

```
Sencha Cmd v6.5.0.180
[WRN] D:\Web\src\trunk\FrontExtJs\.sencha\app contained customized file Microloader_orig.js
[WRN] D:\Web\src\trunk\FrontExtJs\.sencha\app contained customized file sencha.cfg.bak
[WRN] Directory D:\Web\src\trunk\FrontExtJs\.sencha\app could not be removed
[INF] Loading configuration for framework directory: D:\TOOLS\Sencha\ext-6.5.0
[INF] Copying framework to D:\Web\src\trunk\FrontExtJs\ext
[INF] Upgrading to Ext JS 6.x
[INF] Upgrading to sdk at D:\TOOLS\Sencha\ext-6.5.0
[INF] Updating application and workspace from Ext JS 6.2.1.167 / Cmd 6.2.1.29
[WRN] Disabling framework : current version 6.5.0.775 is incompatible with required version 6.2.1.167
[ERR]
[ERR] BUILD FAILED
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExNotFound: Required property file D:\Web\src\trunk\FrontExtJs\.sencha\app\$'{'framework.name'}'.properties does not exist
[ERR]
[ERR] Total time: 0 seconds
[ERR]
[ERR] BUILD FAILED
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException: com.sencha.exceptions.ExNotFound: Required property file D:\Web\src\trunk\FrontExtJs\.sencha\app\$'{'framework.name'}'.properties does not exist
[ERR]
[ERR] Total time: 1 second
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException: com.sencha.exceptions.ExNotFound: Required property file D:\Web\src\trunk\FrontExtJs\.sencha\app\${framework.name}.properties does not exist
[ERR]
[ERR] The application was last modified by an older version of Sencha Cmd (6.2.1.29).
[ERR] Running "sencha app upgrade" may resolve the error described above.
[ERR]
```

Answer (score 2):

*My answer might come too late but at least maybe it will help others:*

I have upgraded a fair number of applications till now (major & minors including nightly builds) and I was rarely able to upgrade an app without **Errors** using the Sencha [Guide](https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/guides/cmd_upgrade.html).

I found that it is much easier and less time consuming to:

- generate another application with the same name
- copy (almost) all your files & folders into the new app (`/app` except **Application.js**, `/overrides, /resources, /sass` etc.)
- manually change (merge) **app.json** file and **Application.js** file from the 2 apps - framework specific declarations might differ.
- run an application build

Note1: Upgrade to the latest Sencha Cmd version (for simplification).

Note2: `sencha upgrade` installs the newer version if exists but does not uninstall the older one(s). Make sure you are using the latest one.

Answer (score 0):

I had to run `sencha app install` which will repopulate missing files. Once I ran that, `sencha app upgrade` ran smoothly. Run `sencha help app install` for more info about it.